# Filtering table data for multiple columns Angular 10

Tags: javascript, angular, rxjs, angular10

I need to filter the table data according to the value I set in the input on `keyup` event. As there are multiple columns, filtered data should be displayed accordingly.

In my html I have below

```html
             <tr>
             <td *ngFor="let t of tableHeader">
               <input type="text" [id]="t.key" (keyup)="inputChange($event)">
               </td>
            </tr>
```

My TS file is as below

```typescript
    public inputChange(value) {
    var prevData = this.dataSource;

    if (this.selectedId == '') {
      prevData = this.result;
    }
    else if (this.selectedId != '' && this.selectedId != value.target.id) {
      prevData = this.result;
    }

     if (this.selectedId != '' && filterValue.target.value == '') {   
       this.result = prevData;
       return;
     }
   
    this.selectedId = value.target.id;
    this.inputValue = value.target.value;

    var filteredData = this.result.filter(x => x[this.selectedId] && x[this.selectedId].toString().toLowerCase().includes(this.inputValue.toLowerCase()));
    this.result = filteredData;
    }
```

So far I have done this and get data filtered accordingly, but when I remove a value from a particular filter input, it loads the data source.

Expected: to display the previously filtered data instead of the data source.

Comment: What do you mean by "remove a value?" Making the input blank or hitting backspace?

Comment: I have made a stackblitz demo, could you say what the issue is? https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-hqamih?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts

Comment: yes @abney317 by hitting backspace it should display previously filtered data

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To achieve this I would use below steps using `rxjs`

1. Define the `datasource` as an `Observable`

```typescript
dataSource = [
    {
      firstname: "James",
      lastname: "Amstrong",
      othernames: "Angel",
      age: 35
    },
    {
      firstname: "John",
      lastname: "Peter",
      othernames: "Ava",
      age: 43
    },
...
]
```

We will convert this `datasource` to an observable using `of` from `'rxjs'`

2. Define the filter as an `Observable`

```typescript
   tableHeader = [
    {
      key: "firstname"
    },
    {
      key: "lastname"
    },
    ...
  ];
 filterKeyValues = this.tableHeader.map(({ key }) => ({ key, value: "" }));
 filterSubject$ = new BehaviorSubject(this.filterKeyValues)
  filter$ = this.filterSubject$.asObservable()
```

This simply generates an `Observable` with the structure

```
Observable<[{ key: firtname, value: ''}, { key: lastname, value: ''}, ...]>
```

3. Combine the two and return a new `Observable` as the new filtered data

```typescript
dataSource$ = combineLatest([
    this.filter$, of(this.dataSource)
  ]).pipe(
    map(([filter, dataSource]) => 
     dataSource.filter(item => 
        filter.every((value) => 
          (new RegExp(String(value.value).toLowerCase())).test(String(item[value.key]).toLowerCase())
          
        )
      )
    )
  )
```

4. Define handler for the `inputChange`

```typescript
  public inputChange(event: any, key) {
    this.filterKeyValues.find(({key: testKey}) => testKey === key).value = event.target.value
    this.filterSubject$.next(this.filterKeyValues)
  }
```

5. Use `async` to display the contents

```html
<table>
    <tr>
        <td *ngFor="let t of tableHeader">
            <input type="text" [id]="t.key" (keyup)="inputChange($event, t.key)">
           </td>
    </tr>
  <tr *ngFor="let item of  dataSource$ | async">
    <td>{{ item.firstname }}</td>
    <td>{{ item.lastname }}</td>
    <td>{{ item.othernames }}</td>
    <td>{{ item.age }}</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

We are calling the next value. this will force a change detection and `datasorce$` `Observable` will be reevaluated causing an update in the UI

I have made a [Demo Here](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-iklpvz?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts) to illustrate this approach